# How to apply style on PolylineDecorator

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, gis, react-leaflet, polyline-decorator

I'm working on project to show the history of GPS device. For every few seconds, location of GPS devices are sent to our SQL server and currently I can use these data and show on map.

```
  function PolylineDecorator({ patterns, polyline }: any) {
    const map = useMap();

    if (!map) return;

    L.polyline(polyline).addTo(map);
    L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
      patterns
    }).addTo(map);

    return null;
  }

  const arrow = [
    {
      color: 'purple',
      offset: 0,
      size: '100%',
      repeat: 50,
      symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
        pixelSize: 7,
        pathOptions: {
          color: 'red',
          weight: 2
        }
      })}  
  ];
```

So these two are my polylinedecorator and arrow. What I want to do is,

1. put a marker or polygon with different color at Start and end point of polyline.

2. To make thicker of polyline

[Because what I did so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P07cN.png), as that GPS device moving around in certain area, it kind of show just like image, which is very difficult to understand the history of GPS device.

Thank you.